# css to PDF using css2pdf@cloudformatter

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, css-to-pdf

i am a newbie in programming. recently tried to use the service provided by css2pdf@cloudformatter. I keep getting these errors while i try to generate a pdf

The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception         message is 'Name cannot begin with the ''' character, hexadecimal value 0x27. Line 64, position 86.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e) at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args) at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributes() at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement() at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent() at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read() at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r) at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r, LoadOptions o) at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options) at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader) at RenderX.WebServices.Worker.ReplaceResources(MemoryStream foStreamOriginal, MemoryStream foStreamLocalResources) in f:\Xportability\Projects\RenderX.WebServices\Src\Worker.cs:line 179 at RenderX.WebServices.Worker.generate(String xml, Attachments attachments, String systemId, String mimeType, IFormatter formatter, Func`1 log, String global404, Boolean& succeed, Boolean genimages, Logger logger) in f:\Xportability\Projects\RenderX.WebServices\Src\Worker.cs:line 66 at RenderX.WebServices.Worker.Process(String xml, Attachments attachments, String systemId, String mimeType, IFormatter formatter, Func`1 log, String global404, Logger logger) in f:\Xportability\Projects\RenderX.WebServices\Src\Worker.cs:line 22 at RenderX.WebServices.Chandra.Format(Stream stream) in f:\Xportability\Projects\RenderX.WebServices\Src\Chandra.svc.cs:line 68 at SyncInvokeFormat(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)

An image of the error log
 [error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfEo0.png)

below is my code:

```
 <button class="btn btn-success pull-right"  onclick="return xepOnline.Formatter.Format('wrapper', {pageWidth:'216mm', pageHeight:'279mm'});">
        <i class="fa fa-print"></i><b>Print</b>
```

i have included the xepOnline.jqPlugin.js and jquery plugins. 
Thanks in anticipation of help

Comment: There is an illegal character (according to XML standard) used in the name of some attribute passed to the formatter. We have tried to filter many of these out in the code but you must be passing something not planned. There are debugging hints here http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.APIDoc.DebuggingHints (line numbers likely different) where you can capture and send to us the data to examine.

Comment: Kevin!!! You are a genius. I appreciate your efforts in salvaging the situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to wind this up with an answer as it was taken offline to solve. An examination of the data being sent to the server showed that the OP had some invalid HTML which the browser did not clear up and passed through. This was an attribute ' on an img tag.

```
 <img style="display: inline; float: none; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; vertical-align: middle; width: 200px; position: static; top: auto; left: auto; bottom: auto; right: auto;" src="../../uploads/admin_images/user5.jpg" alt="Uchechukwu" '="" class="img-rounded" width="200" height="200"/>
```

this '="" attribute was being parsed as XML and hence the error.